# Simple rspec test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I would have thought this test would have passed. Any ideas why it isnt?

```
it 'should create an account' do
  visit new_user_registration_path
  fill_in 'user_email', with: 'newtest@test.com'
  fill_in 'user_password', with: 'testing123'
  fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', with: 'testing123'
  expect{
    click_button 'Sign Up'
  }.to change{User.count}.by(1)
end
```

I just get

```
result should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

Comment: Are you sure that there are no errors during the signup? what does current_path give you after the sign up step?

Comment: Exactly the same example work in my app(with devise). Maybe your user have any other validation require? When you make those steps manualy everything working good?

Answer (score 0):

It is a counter cache problem, see this:
[Rails counter_cache not updating correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403577/rails-counter-cache-not-updating-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake. I had a validation on user for name!