# Rails 4 counter cache out of sync

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, counter-cache

I have a Rails 4.2 app with a counter cache (setup with `belongs_to :my_model, counter_cache: true`) that is setting incorrect values. I can literally call up the console and call `MyModel.associated_model_count` and get `20`, and then call `MyModel.associated_model.count` and get `19`. Saving the model does not fix this.

The values don't seem to be off by much, but some are definitely off and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You need to reproduce the circumstances that first cause it to go wrong. Once it's gone wrong there's nothing you can do (other than update the counter manually)

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this? I'm seeing the same thing where the model_count is HIGHER than the model.count. Not sure how that can happen. A reset does work, but doesn't fix the root issue of it getting out of sync in the first place.

Comment: I am 'me too'ing this because we are seeing this as well. We are never (ok, rarely) destroying. I am wondering if it is failing on failed creates?

Answer (score 8):

To answer part of your question and hopefully help you in debugging, the counter column is only updated on `create` and `destroy`, so saving the object wouldn't trigger a counter update.  More detail can be found under the `:counter_cache` entry under Options here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

You can manually trigger a counter update using `MyModel.reset_counters(id, *counters)` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/reset_counters) if you want to get to a clean state in order to pinpoint where it goes off.

Related question with helpful answers and discussion: [Rails counter_cache not updating correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403577/rails-counter-cache-not-updating-correctly)

Comment: But how would it go out of sync in the first place? And how would the model_count  go HIGHER than the model.count? Assuming you are not doing any deleting, destroying, or moving.